# python scrapy not removing \n from string

Tags: python, scrapy, newline

i have around 200 values ive done everything to remove new line character '\n'
tried all this

```
prodname = str(row['productname'])
prodname = ''.join(prodname.split('[u\'\n', 1))
prodname = ''.join(prodname.split('[u\'', 1))
prodname = ''.join(prodname.split('\']', 1))
prodname = ''.join(prodname.split('\n', 1))
prodname = prodname.replace('\n', '')
```

still my values look like this...any idea why???

[image]

**UPDATE:**

here is the spider code

```
class ShopBot(Spider):
    name = "shopbot"
    allowed_domains = ["shopbot.com.au"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.shopbot.com.au/apple-iphone-unlocked/price/australia/13721",
        "http://www.shopbot.com.au/m/?m=apple-iphone-unlocked&page=2"
        "http://www.shopbot.com.au/m/?m=apple-iphone-unlocked&page=3",
        "http://www.shopbot.com.au/laptops/laptop,-tablet-pda/australia/115",
        "http://www.shopbot.com.au/laptops/laptop,-tablet-pda/australia/115/order/0/page/2",
        "http://www.shopbot.com.au/laptops/laptop,-tablet-pda/australia/115/order/0/page/3",
        "http://www.shopbot.com.au/laptops/laptop,-tablet-pda/australia/115/order/0/page/4",
        "http://www.shopbot.com.au/laptops/laptop,-tablet-pda/australia/115/order/0/page/5"
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        sel = Selector(response)
        prodsel = sel.xpath('//div[@id="content"]/div[@class="left"]/ul[@id="results"]/li[@class="result"]/ol')

        #productnames = sel.xpath('//ul[@class="navigation"]/li/dl/dt[@class="title"]/a/text()').extract()
        #price = sel.xpath('//ul[@class="navigation"]/li/dl/dd[@class="price"]/span[@class="main"]/text()').extract()
        items = []
        for site in prodsel:
            item = ArgosItems()
            item['productname'] = site.xpath('li[@class="details"]/span[@rel="external"]/text()').extract()
            item['price'] = site.xpath('li[@class="action"]/div[@class="price"]/span/text()').extract()
            item['siteid'] = 2
            items.append(item)
        return items
```

and this is where im processing it to save it in db

```
def spider_closed(spider):
    config = {
          'user': 'root',
          'password': 'root',
          'host': '127.0.0.1',
          'database': 'pricewatch',
          'raise_on_warnings': True,
          'buffered': True,
        }
    cnx = mysql.connector.connect(**config)
    cursor = cnx.cursor()
    today = datetime.now()
    print today

    count = 0

    for row in results:

        prodname = str(row['productname'])
        prodname = ''.join(prodname.split('[u\'\n', 1))
        prodname = ''.join(prodname.split('[u\'', 1))
        prodname = ''.join(prodname.split('\']', 1))
        prodname = ''.join(prodname.split('\n', 1))
        prodname = prodname.replace('\n', '')

        price = str(row['price'])
        price = ''.join(price.split('$', 1))
        price = ''.join(price.split('[u\'', 1))
        price = ''.join(price.split('\']', 1))
        price = ''.join(price.split('\n', 1))
        price = price.replace('\n','')

        siteid = row['siteid']
```

**NOTE: I am running scrapy from python script called pricewatch.py**

Comment: Could you post your entire spider code please, so we can see if the problem lies elsewhere?

Comment: "ive done everything to remove new line character '\n'". Have you tried simply doing `yourstring.strip()`?

Comment: @Talvalin ive updated the question with spider code

Comment: @Pawelmhm yes ive tried strip, lstrip, rstrip

Comment: When I run your spider I don't get any newlines in fields. How are you calling this spider_closed function? Where does results in spider_closed come from? If you want to save items to database you need to use pipelines.

Comment: yes im doing that... i will update the question tonight again with complete code

Comment: Do newlines still appear if you output your results to a csv file, without using the spider_closed code and pipeline?